# "The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192"

Tags: apt, gnupg

```
$ sudo apt-get update
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/Release  
W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I remove these warnings? Running `apt-get update` has given me these warnings from the beginning of my fresh 10.10 install.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Option 1**

From [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-extras-keyring/+bug/650525):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-extras-keyring
```

**Option 2**

See [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-gpg-error-httpextras-ubuntu-com-maverick-release.html).

Summary:

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 3E5C1192
gpg --export --armor 3E5C1192 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This is more concise: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192`